# "Attempted to redefine prop" error with T::Struct

Tags: sorbet

I'm trying to make use of T::Struct to avoid some boilerplate in a class:

https://github.com/andyw8/codeclimate-engine-rb/pull/13/commits/d1fd72e22a4b9737ef2fe759215fb1c73c25e3bb

`srb tc` doesn't report any errors, but when I run the tests it fails with:

```
ArgumentError:
  Attempted to redefine prop :check_name that's already defined without specifying :override => true: {:type=>String, :type_is_custom_type=>nil, :type_is_serializable=>nil, :type_is_array_of_serializable=>false, :type_is_hash_of_serializable_values=>false, :type_is_hash_of_custom_type_keys=>false, :type_object=>#<T::Types::Simple:0x00007fc611266e78 @raw_type=String>, :type_needs_clone=>false, :accessor_key=>:@check_name, :sensitivity=>nil, :pii=>nil, :extra=>nil, :serialized_form=>"check_name", :fully_optional=>false, :need_nil_read_check=>nil}
# /Users/awaite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.5188/lib/types/props/decorator.rb:56:in `add_prop_definition'
# /Users/awaite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.5188/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:126:in `call'
# /Users/awaite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.5188/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:126:in `validate_call'
# /Users/awaite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.5188/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:186:in `block in create_validator_slow'
# /Users/awaite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.5188/lib/types/props/optional.rb:48:in `add_prop_definition'
# /Users/awaite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.5188/lib/types/props/serializable.rb:311:in `add_prop_definition'
# /Users/awaite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.5188/lib/types/props/decorator.rb:490:in `prop_defined'
# /Users/awaite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.5188/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:126:in `call'
# /Users/awaite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.5188/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:126:in `validate_call'
# /Users/awaite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.5188/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:186:in `block in create_validator_slow'
# /Users/awaite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.5188/lib/types/props/_props.rb:109:in `prop'
# ./lib/cc_engine/issue.rb:8:in `<class:Issue>'
```

If I re-order the props, I get the same error but for `description` instead.

Is it perhaps because I'm using a struct but also defining methods on it? I know Ruby's `Struct` supports that but I'm not sure about Sorbet's `T::Struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I had to add a dependency, `require "cc_engine/location"` (although I don't yet understand why it caused that particular error message).

Comment: Based on my own issue, I imagine the error is caused by Sorbet not knowing about the type yet.  In your case, `require "cc_engine/location"` fixes it because it forces the `CCEngine::Location` types used on [line 11](https://github.com/andyw8/codeclimate-engine-rb/pull/13/commits/d1fd72e22a4b9737ef2fe759215fb1c73c25e3bb#diff-df2bf10109317a41b1c3e11861edb1568d95372630b2a763a78b9a8c6b3382a5R11) to load _(I have no idea why they wouldn't be loaded already, however)_

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to type a value prior to its type being defined

```
class MyStruct < T::Struct
  extend T::Sig

  const :some_const, MyEnumType

  class MyEnumType < T::Enum
    ...
  end
end
```

Moving the definition of `MyEnumType` to be *above* the definition of `some_const` fixed the issue.